# Using permutations itertools with constraints (Python)

Tags: python, loops, permutation

I have a list of numbers and I want to get all possible permutations of it considering some constraint.

for example if we have a list of numbers as follows:

num=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

I want to have 1 and 6 alwayas as first and last element of list and "2" should come always before "3" and "4" should come always before "5".
my code looks like following code:
...

```
for p in itertools.permutations(numbers):
    if p[0] == 1 and p[-1]== 6:
        for i,j in zip([2,3],[4,5]):
           
            if p.index(i)<p.index(j):
                print(p)
```

...
the problem is that for each Iteration, the code considers just on of constraints:

1 2 3 5 4 6 ---> 2 before 3 but 4 is not before 5.

1 3 2 4 5 6 ---> 4 before 5 but 2 is not before 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user is asking users to solve what it seems to be his assignment.

Comment: I have Problem with implementing one part of my code that I have searched enough and did not find a solution for that obviously its not an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that whenever one of the checks succeeds, the print will run, without regard for the other check. You could rewrite your code using a flag like so

```
for p in itertools.permutations(numbers):
    if p[0] == 1 and p[-1]== 6:
        valid = True
        for i,j in ((2, 3), (4, 5)):
            if p.index(i) > p.index(j):
                valid = False
        if valid:
            print(p)
```

Or more concisely using `break`:

```
for p in itertools.permutations(numbers):
    if p[0] == 1 and p[-1]== 6:
        for i,j in ((2, 3), (4, 5)):
            if p.index(i) > p.index(j):
                break
        else:
            print(p)
```

Comment: this code limits the answers, but the main problem exists yet. as example :(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6) 2 is before 3 but 5 is not before 4.

Comment: In the output I'm not getting (1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6). Also note I changed `zip([2,3],[4,5])` to `((2, 3), (4, 5))`, as you were effectively checking 2 was before 4 and 3 before 5, instead of the desired constraints.

Comment: thanks thats true. I did not changed the zip part.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is not working is because you are looking at each condition individually, rather than at the same time. This means if one set works for both conditions, it will be printed twice! Instead, you should try something like:

```py
for p in itertools.permutations(numbers):
    if p[0] == 1 and p[-1]== 6:
      if p.index(2) < p.index(3) and p.index(4) < p.index(5):        
           print(p)
```

Comment: That´s true is did it the same way and it did work but if we have different list with different elements it will not work anymore I need to do it in a dynamic way.